# Devise let me to change new password as empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This is my code for changing a password:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protect_from_forgery

  def update_password

    if current_user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
      sign_in(current_user, bypass: true)
      redirect_to settings_path, notice: "updated"
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, alert: current_user.errors.full_messages
    end

  end

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(_resource)
  end

  def after_update_path_for(_resource)
    settings_path
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
  
  private

    def user_params
      # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
      params.require(:user).permit(:current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

The code works if I enter my current password and set a new one, but it doesn't when I enter a correct current password and as a new password + confirmation I leave empty fields (empty string).

The password will not get changed as "no password", but I get a flash message "updated". How do prevent that? I can think of this:

```
  if current_user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
      if params[:user][:password].blank?
        redirect_to settings_path, alert: "blank pswd"
        return
      end
      
      sign_in(current_user, bypass: true)
      redirect_to settings_path, notice: "Your password has been updated!"
    else
      redirect_to settings_path, alert: current_user.errors.full_messages
    end
```

However, this solution is a bit... ugly. Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question I was a bit surprised about this behavior. But looking at the [source code](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L83) I could confirm that this behavior is expected and describe in a comment in the code:

> ```
> # This method also rejects the password field if it is blank (allowing
> # users to change relevant information like the e-mail without changing
> # their password). In case the password field is rejected, the confirmation
> # is also rejected as long as it is also blank.
> ```

I have mixed feelings about how to handle it. I would probably not show an error message because when the user didn't enter a new password they probably would not expect the password to change.

But another way to handle the error message could be to not handle that case in the method at all but to use a [`before_action`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action):

```
before_action :ensure_new_password_provided, only: :update_password

private

  def ensure_new_password_provided
    return if params[:user][:password].present?
    redirect_to settings_path, alert: "blank pswd"
  end
```